# Firebase queryOrderedByKey nested keys

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

How can I order all nested children by key (by default) in Firebase?

For example:

```
    users: {
        abc: {
            qwe: true,
            qwf: true
        },
        abd: {
            qwe: true,
            qwf: true
        }
    }
```

I want this data to come back as it is, `users` should be ordered by key (which carries the information of when they were created, since I'm using `childByAutoId`), and the nested values should also be ordered by key.

Effectively I want all my data to be ordered by creation order.

I tried `queryOrderedByKey()`, but it doesn't order the nested values.

Obs.: In other words, I want the data to come back ordered in the same way as presented in Firebase's dashboard.

Comment: What did you try? Because what you're describing is the default order of Firebase, so likely you're doing something different than what I expect without seeing code.

Comment: I tried getting the value with and without queryOrderedByKey(). In both cases, the nest value doesn't come ordered.

Comment: As @FrankvanPuffelen said, that's the natural order of Firebase. The dashboard displays them ordered by key, so if your code ordersByKey, you'll get the same result. Please post some code so we can see what's causing the issue. As another thought, if you are storing when the user was created in each user node, why not order it by that?

Comment: Well, I was hoping the key already had that information (not to give me the time itself, but to order). In any case, how can I order the nested types? I'll update the question with some code for how I'm querying, but I'm observing single event .Value for "/users".